# How to link to Winsock when cross-compiling a Windows app on Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, cross-compiling, winsock

I am porting a Cmake project from Linux to Windows. It uses sockets, so uses pthread in Linux and needs Winsock in Windows.

The project is being compiled in Linux, using cross-compilation to create Windows binaries.

The project is already compiling fine, and there is a switch to link pthreads when building for Linux and winsock for Windows.

However, there is a linking issue with sockets, it seems that winsock is not found.

Here is part of the Cmake file I am using :

```
find_library(lib1 wsock32)
find_library(lib2 ws2_32)

message("${lib1}  ${lib2}")

if (WIN32)
    target_link_libraries (TaskTool wsock32 ws2_32)
endif(WIN32)
```

And here is the output I get :

```
lib1-NOTFOUND  lib2-NOTFOUND
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: 
Linking CXX executable TaskTool.exe
ToolsLib/libToolsLib.a(networkwaker.cpp.obj):networkwaker.cpp:(.text+0x522): referência indefinida a `_imp__socket@12'
ToolsLib/libToolsLib.a(networkwaker.cpp.obj):networkwaker.cpp:(.text+0x559): referência indefinida a `_imp__setsockopt@20'
ToolsLib/libToolsLib.a(networkwaker.cpp.obj):networkwaker.cpp:(.text+0x596): referência indefinida a `_imp__bind@12'
ToolsLib/libToolsLib.a(networkwaker.cpp.obj):networkwaker.cpp:(.text+0x5b0): referência indefinida a `_imp__inet_addr@4'
ToolsLib/libToolsLib.a(networkwaker.cpp.obj):networkwaker.cpp:(.text+0x5c3): referência indefinida a `_imp__htons@4'
ToolsLib/libToolsLib.a(networkwaker.cpp.obj):networkwaker.cpp:(.text+0x614): referência indefinida a `_imp__sendto@24'
```

How is the proper way to add/link to winsock? I understand that winsock is not readily available in Linux as it is a Windows library.

- Is there a standard package I can install to have it? (like apt-get install windowssdk...).
- Should I copy it manually and link it from a Windows installation?
- Is there something I need to add to the Cmake toolchain file?

Here is the toolchain file I am using :

```
SET(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER   /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc)
SET(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER /usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-g++)
```

Comment: Looking at those undefined symbol names, they look very much like the entry points you'd find for those function in `ws2_32.lib`.  I am *NOT* a mingw expert so I have no idea if this will actually work, but try installing Visual Studio Community on your Windows system.  Among other things, that'll install the full Windows SDK somewhere under `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits`.  Have a dig round in there for `ws2_32.lib` and then do whatever it takes to make that file get included in your link.

Comment: Found [a link to this](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/cmake/cross_compiling/Mingw) from the old [CmakeMingw entry on the CMake wiki](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CmakeMingw), which I found using Google. That first link provides an example toolchain file that appears to be very close to what you'll need, based on the fact that it looks like you're using a cross-compile toolchain obtained using your system's package manager (i.e. `ls /usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/libwsock32.a` doesn't yield an error, assuming my guess is correct).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some while testing various configuration, I finally found out how to solve the issue :

1. Get ws2_32.lib directly from Windows installation. No need to install Windows SDK.
2. Link to it using a path name :

   `target_link_libraries (TaskTool ToolsLib "${TOOLS_ROOT}/ToolsLib/lib/ws2_32.lib")`
3. **Include directly on the dependencies the module that will need it**. Without cross-compiling that was not necessary, but now it is.

With these 3 steps the program builds fine. However, it doesn't run on Windows. In order to do so, additional changes are necessary :

1. Link statically C runtime environment :

`target_link_libraries (TaskTool "-static-libgcc" "-static-libstdc++")`

2. Provide **libwinpthread-1.dll** in the same folder as the executable. I didnt' find it on my OS, so I downloaded it.